# Passing a GraphQL query to a nested map in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql

### Explantion

I'm passing data from this GraphQL query below to a nested map function, but I keep getting `node.map is not a function` even though it's inside an array. I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, so any guidance would be appreciated. ;)

### Code

**Query**

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulAwards {
    edges {
      node {
        year
        championships {
          contest
          title {
            key
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data**

```
{
  "data": {
    "allContentfulAwards": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "year": "2021",
            "championships": [
              {
                "contestName": "Contest1",
                "titles": [
                  {
                    "key": "TitleA"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "TitleB"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "contestName": "Contest2",
                "titles": [
                  {
                    "key": "TitleA"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "year": "2020",
            "championships": [
              {
                "contestName": "Contest1",
                "titles": [
                  {
                    "key": "TitleA"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Nested map**

```
{
  data.allContentfulAwards.edges.map(({node}) => (
    <div>
      {node.ano}
      {node.map(({championships}) => (
        <AwardsCollapse name={championships.contestName}>
          {championships.map(({titles}) => (
            <p>{titles.key}</p>
          ))}
        </AwardsCollapse>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Luiz.

Comment: `node.championships.map(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luiz, the `map` function in JavaScript is associated with `arrays`. You're trying to use the `map` function on `node`, which is an `object`.

Use the code below to get your desired result.

```
{
  data.allContentfulAwards.edges.map(({node}) => (
    <div>
      {node.year}
      {node.championships.map(({contestName, titles}) => (
        <AwardsCollapse name={contestName}>
          {titles.map(({key}) => (
            <p>{key}</p>
          ))}
        </AwardsCollapse>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

~Prayag

Comment: Yes! I misunderstood thinking that `node` being inside an array would be enough. Thank you for your explanation, but I think you missed some code here. I edited it with the final solution.